# Gene configuration : Divergent vs convergent

Tags: genomics, t7-promoter

I start reading a paper where they discuss the effect of the **divergent promoter/gene** and the **convergent promoter/gene** on the genetic expression of an organism.

So I want to know what is the difference between the two of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RNA polymerase produces transcripts by scanning along DNA, linearly. Simplifying things, genes can thus be thought of as having a start (or 5' end) which is the main site where the polymerase begins to transcribe, and and end, where it stops. Divergent promoters are promoters oriented so that the polymerase transcribes in opposite directions, away from the two promoters (like so: <- -> ). Convergent promoters instead transcribe towards each other (like so -> <- ) . This means, for instance, that the polymerases coming from two convergent promoters could collide with one another.